# Creating a function that fires after an element comes into existence

Tags: jquery, dom

I am creating an element with `.append` in jQuery.  I have a function that I want to execute when the element exists.

I find that immediately after the append command is run, the element does not exist.  So how can I make it execute upon it's existence?

Comment: That is not true, `.append()` happens immediately and the elements are accessible immediately.

Comment: need to post code... if you append and then call function it will find element if it exists

Comment: *"...after an element comes into existence"* - and element was born ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can bind to the `DOMNodeInserted` event, but be aware that you lose support for IE8 and older when you do this:

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', '.my-element-class', function () {
    $(this).css({ backgroundColor : 'red' });
});
```

Here's the MDN docs for events, look under "Mutation Events": https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference

Although, the element **does** exist after you append it to the DOM, so you are probably trying to select it incorrectly:

```
$('body').append('<div>My New Div!</div>').children().last().css({ backgroundColor : 'red' });
```

Here is a demo showing that you can select an element directly after you add it to the DOM: http://jsfiddle.net/AH6RG/

Note that this code uses the fact that `.append()` adds the new element as the last child of the container it's added to. So you can select it by selecting the children of the container, then selecting the last child.